# Does accelerating magnet emit radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, acceleration

Just like accelerating charge produces emits radiation, does an accelerating magnet emit electromagnetic radiation?

Comment: Do accelerating dipole moments, electric or magnetic, radiate?

Comment: [I've just posted a related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391558/does-an-accelerating-electric-dipole-radiate)

Comment: have a look at this paper , which says yes and is doing calculations https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0927650514001017

Comment: Any solutions anybody?

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer, but since there has been no other answer in the last 24 hours I will post in the hope it is helpful.

We know an accelerated charge produces electromagnetic radiation because that's how radio transmitters work. So if you wave an eletric charge around it will radiate. Similarly, if you wave a magnetic charge around it would radiate.

The problem is that a magnetic charge would be a [magnetic monopole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole) and as far as we know these do not exist. The magnets we all played with as children are magnetic **dipoles** not magnetic charges. So the question is whether a magnetic dipole radiates when you wave it around.

And this is where we run into problems because the answer to this apparently simple question seems obscure. I have posted a question [Does an accelerating electric dipole radiate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391558/does-an-accelerating-electric-dipole-radiate) to ask this question, but at the time of writing there is no answer to it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. May be doing an experiment will give answer...

Comment: @tiredandboreddev  if you look at the  numbers in the links I gave the energy is so low that it will need a really  good lab to see it. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0927650514001017#s0030 the value for the cornell electron synchrtron is ~10^-34 MeV

Answer (score 0):

In classical electrodynamics any changing charge or current distribution is accompanied by radiation.
Antennas are required to make the emission of radiation efficient.