# Are Magnet Lasers Possible?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, laser

Are there any theories concerning the possibility of `magnet lasers`? A magnet laser would be similar to an optical laser, but instead of light it sends a concentrated beam of magnetic force. Is this even theoretically possible?

Comment: By "concentrated beam of magnetic force," do you mean oscillations in the magnetic field which, in a certain range of wavelengths, are more commonly referred to as "light?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [The stimulated emission of light](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/optmod/qualig.html#c2) is the crucial quantum process necessary for the operation of a laser.

To get lasing action one has to create an electromagnetic field.

Accelerating electric dipoles can radiate, as seen in the chosen [answer here.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391558/does-an-accelerating-electric-dipole-radiate). The mathematics will be analogous for accelerating magnetic dipoles, so accelerating a magnet will generate radiation, and elaborate technology may allow having a coherent enough radiation to create a laser. It would be a very inefficient way both in difficulty in the experiment and in money spent. There are much easier ways of getting coherent electromagnetic waves.